Anyone can translate this JPQL to mySQL
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email = :email")
Optional<User> findByEmailWithRoles(@Param("email") String email);

I like to use mysql but this query blows my mind. After spending 3 HOURS community say me this is not sql -- this is something called JPQL.
But i want to use sql. Is anyone solve my issue

use: "SELECT u. FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email = :email"* to get all fields from the table. Or write every field you wand like "SELECT u.usernam, u.email FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email = :email"

thanks for answer. It is knowledge boosting answer. Thankyou once again

JPQL is abbreviation of Jakarta Persistence Query Language, JPQL  has join fetch in order to better handling of eager fetching in a single query
reference,
you can use following query in MySQL
SELECT u.* 
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE u.email = 'email_value';`

